# Adding View On Top Of Nav Bar and Tab Bar

Tags: swift, view, navbar, tabbar

This is my code which goes in viewDidLoad(), it is a setup for the view that gets poppued up (moved to the middle of the screen) when I click the add button.

```
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(addEntryView)
    addEntryView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    addEntryView.dropShadow()
    self.addEntryView.layer.borderWidth = 5
    self.addEntryView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.31, green:0.72, blue:0.95, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    addEntryView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    addEntryView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 370, height: 695)
    view.addSubview(addEntryView)
```

But it is behind my Nav Bar and Tab Bar. I did find this line of code which gets it above the two, bu then when I switch tabs, the view remains on top of the screen.

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(addEntryView)
```

Any help with getting the view on top of the nav and tab bars but only being for that tab so when I switch tabs, it goes away?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason for "why the view remains at the top when your switching the tabs" is that: you are trying to `addSubview` to the `keyWindow` but not on the `view` of any particular `viewController` hence it will be applied on the top of all the viewControllers.

You need to remove this from `superView` before switching tabs in `viewWillDisapper` or in any other function which is called when you are about to switch tabs.

**Alternatively**, you can make this popup view as a separate viewController with `modalPresentationStyle` equal to `UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext` and present this over your current view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of below code to load a view on top of everything

```
var transperantView = UIView()
if  let appDelegate =  UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
        let window = appDelegate.window {
    transperantView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: window.bounds.width, height:  window.bounds.height)
    transperantView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.09, green:0.157, blue:0.2, alpha:0.75)
    window.addSubview(transperantView)
}
```